# Save results form rand() to new files?

Tags: php, random

I'm trying to figure out how to save results from the `rand()` function to 10 different files.

Here's my code:

```
<?php 
for($i = 0; $i < 10; $i++)
{
    $rand_valuec = rand(0,16); 
    echo "<b>Your Lucky Number is</b>: " . $rand_valuec . " <br />";
    $fp = fopen("results.php", "w");
    fwrite($fp, $rand_valuec); 
    fclose($fp);
}
```

**Sample output**:

```
Your Lucky Number is: 6 
Your Lucky Number is: 16 
Your Lucky Number is: 16 
Your Lucky Number is: 8 
Your Lucky Number is: 6 
Your Lucky Number is: 10 
Your Lucky Number is: 13 
Your Lucky Number is: 5 
Your Lucky Number is: 6 
Your Lucky Number is: 5
```

**results.php** contains:

```
5
```

I need to save each result to a new file; e.g. `1result.php`, `2result.php`, `3result.php`, `4result.php`, `...`, `10result.php`. Any ideas? :-) Thanks!

Comment: I mean, you could change your file pointer to `fopen($i . "result.php", "w")` instead

Comment: PHP uses `.` as a concatenator

Comment: @Jnatalzia Yes it does; can you tell I've been working in JS most of the day? :p

Comment: to 10 differnt files?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could just change your file open to read:

`$fp = fopen($i."result.php", "w");`

Answer (score 2):

```
<?php 
for($i=0; $i < 10; $i++)
{
$rand_valuec = rand(0,16); 
echo "<b>Your Lucky Number is</b>: ".$rand_valuec." <br />";
$fp = fopen($i."results.php", "w");
fwrite($fp, $rand_valuec); 
fclose($fp);
}
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

try it:

```
<?php 

$numberOfFiles = 10;
$numberOfLinesPerFile = 10;

$path = "/home/your-user/your-path/";

for ($fileIndex = 1; $fileIndex <= $numberOfFiles; $fileIndex++) {

    $contentFile = "";

    for ($i = 0; $i < $numberOfLinesPerFile; $i++) { 

        $rand_valuec = rand(0,16); 
        $content = "<b>Your Lucky Number is</b>: ".$rand_valuec." <br />";
    }

    file_put_contents($path . $fileIndex . "result.php", $content);
}
```